# How to put before numbers a fixed three letters code?

Tags: postgresql, replace, regexp-replace

I am quite new in regular expression so I am having confusion in replacing numbers inside a string, in which several id numbers (from 1 to 5 digits, up to now) are separated by commas and closed between curly brackets.
I need to put before each written number a fixed code like **p1_** in order to distinguish in future different types of objects' ids.
I have postgres database with a column "maintainance" in text format which can contains values like the followings (cells CAN'T BE null or empty):

```
+---------------+
| maintainance  |
+---------------+
| {12541,2,4}   |
+---------------+
| {12,131,9999} |
+---------------+
| {54}          |
+---------------+
| {1}           |
+---------------+
| {12500,65}    |
+---------------+
```

and I'd need to replace values putting before each number "p1_" like this:

```
+------------------------+
| maintainance           |
+------------------------+
| {p1_12541,p1_2,p1_4}   |
+------------------------+
| {p1_12,p1_131,p1_9999} |
+------------------------+
| {p1_54}                |
+------------------------+
| {p1_1}                 |
+------------------------+
| {p1_12500,p1_65}       |
+------------------------+
```

can you please suggest me how to write replace command using regular expressions ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What data type is that column? The display seems to suggest that those are arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
regexp_replace(col, '[0-9]+', 'p_1\&', 'g')
```

Comment: No Laurenz, with the code you wrote the letters "p1_" are not puf before existing numbers, they completely substitute them i.e. {p_1&,p_1&,p_1&}

Comment: Sorry, example fixed.